# Question about BTC-E fee's

Tags: exchanges, exchange-rate, btce, exchange-fees

I'm looking into trading on btc-e but can't find too much info on the trading fees. All I see is a general 2%. Is there a fee for trading btc in or out? What else is there? What's the 2% calculated off of?

Answer (score 1):

0.2% is taken from each trade, so if you sold BTC for $100 USD you'd get $99.80 in your account.

Coin deposits are free, withdrawals are subject to a generous miners fee.

Fiat deposits/withdrawals vary from something like 1% to 6% I can't recall off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

> Fiat deposits/withdrawals vary from something like 1% to 6% I can't recall off the top of my head.

That depends on the payment method, wire transfers for example are 1% (and quite slow btw) and online payment systems are more expenses (and many of them are very questionable)

When I want to trade at btc-e I usually buy bitcoins using faster services, than send bitcoins to btc-e